# Does Apple allow animated elements in menubar apps?

Tags: app-store, osx-yosemite, menubar, mac-app-store

I have a menubar app wherein I would like to make some of the elements that appear live in the menubar animated for user feedback, etc.  Do Apple App Store guidelines or does their policy prevent a developer from being able to do this?

I have searched, but have not been able to find any policy or statement regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guidelines are guidelines and not rules. Yes they allow.